# What are the byproducts of ozonolysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, ozone

I understand that ozonolysis of alkenes leads to formation of aldehydes or ketones or carboxylic acids depending on the type of work up, reductive or oxidative.

But when I tried searching online I couldn't find anything about the side products.

In summary my question is

"What are the by products when an alkene, say but-2-ene undergoes reductive ozonolysis(with Zn/H2O) and oxidative ozonolysis(H2O2) separately, in each case?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reductive ozonolysis, we get the ***Carbonyl compounds***, and ***Zinc(II) oxide***.

In oxidative ozonolysis (where we use water), we initially get the ***carbonyl compounds*** and ***Hydrogen peroxide***. This hyrdogen Peroxide often reacts with aldehyde (if formed) to form the respective ***carboxylic acids*** and ***water***.